# Continuous Maps from Metric Spaces into R

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $x \in X$. Consider the closed ball $B[x, \epsilon]$ then give an example of a function $$f:B[x, \epsilon] \to [0, 1]$$ such that $f(x)=0$ and for all the points $y$ such that $d(x, y)=\epsilon$, we have $f(y)=1$

Comment: HINT: If you can do it when $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, so that $B[x,\epsilon]=[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$, you should be able to do it in general.

Comment: What about $f(y)=\frac1\varepsilon d(x,y)$?